# Binary Message Comparison

Tags: java, encoding, ibm-mq, oracle-service-bus, osb

We just came across an interesting issue which we face during unit testing of the response flow of a message transformation.
The outcome of this flow is an (XML to NON XML)Binary output which is put on the queue. 
The issue we are facing is:
The length of this binary output message doesn’t match with that of the non-xml data, which we save as our expected result from the MFL format tester tool. Our inference is that OSB internally applies some encoding to this message which by the looks of it is UTF-8 present in Proxy/Business Service. So we changed the encoding of the expected to UTF-8 and the test case was successful. But on close investigation it was found that
UTF-8 by its own virtue does not represent all the data correctly. Where ever there is a data loss it is represented with a ‘? ‘ symbol. 
Hence our comparison is incorrect even though the JUNIT test case passes.

And also there is MQ in between which might have its own encoding, which we are unable to rule out at this moment.

We can think of two solutions to this:
1.  We can implement the Comparison by converting both the expected and obtained into a Byte[] to avoid any encoding issues. But we are unable to obtain the exact message length in the output.
2.  We can encode both expected and obtained result into a common encoding format other than UTF-8, but we are not sure which, and then do the comparison.

Any ideas gang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely not experiencing data loss when you look at the UTF-8 encoded binary data and see a question mark (?).  Odds are much better that you have a incomplete font set installed on your computer and there is no character to display the particular unicode character specified in the file.  There is a smaller chance that your binary to UTF-8 conversion routine is using a character which lacks a glyph.

If the binaries didn't match, you should have fixed the problem there.   Odds are that one of the binaries encodes an end of string sequence, end of file sequence, an end of transmission sequence, or some set of bits which confuses a program into thinking it's done when more data is actually present).

Either that or you are incorrectly casting a binary into a string sequence.  Binary comparisons should be made at the byte level, and in Java you can't assume bytes == chars.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Edwin, yes we looked to fix our binaries first but are as yet unable to determine the length mismatch. may be its  something to do with MOM. if '?' is not necessarily a data loss so does it ensure that '?' always represents the same underlying binary data?

Comment: it turned out to be problem with the binaries.